# Not in or Not exist Query Very Slow for Large Data Sybase

Tags: sql, sybase

I have a table A which is having around 50000 records and a table B which is having 50000 records as well.
sample data:

```
A                   B
1                   1      
2                   2
3                   null
4                   null
```

I want to find records 3, 4 which are present in Table A but not in Table B.
I am using

```
select id from A where id NOT IN(select id from B)
```

I have also tried NOT Exist, but as the records are very large in number, it still takes a lot of time.

```
 select id from A where NOT Exists(select id from B and B.id = A.id)
```

Left Outer Join cant be used to find the missing records as the id is not present in Table B.

Is there any way to make the Query Work Faster in Sybase itself?
Or Shifting the database to MongoDB is the solution?

Comment: Is `LEFT JOIN` gives you wrong data, why not prefer that?

Comment: I cant use left join to get missing record...Join can be done if id is present in both tables A and B..in this case...id is present only in table A..

Comment: Is this query return your expected result `SELECT T1.Id FROM A T1 LEFT JOIN B T2 ON T2.Id = T1.Id WHERE T2.Id IS NULL` ?

Comment: No it returns zero records..as you have done Join on Id..

SELECT T1.Id FROM A T1 LEFT JOIN B T2 ON T2.Id = T1.Id

returns first two records

Comment: Little confusion, your expected result is 3 and 4 right?

Comment: yes that is the expected result.

Comment: 50000 records is not a lot of data. Do you have indexes in place?

Comment: I agree with Salmon. have proper indexes and `not exists` should do just fine

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you are not prepare LEFT JOIN, I tried with the `LEFT JOIN` it returns your expected result.

Sample execution with the given data:

```
DECLARE @TableA TABLE (Id INT);
DECLARE @TableB TABLE (Id INT);

INSERT INTO @TableA (Id) VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4);
INSERT INTO @TableB (Id) VALUES (1), (2), (NULL), (NULL);

SELECT T1.Id
FROM @TableA T1
LEFT JOIN @TableB T2 ON T2.Id = T1.Id
WHERE T2.Id IS NULL
```

Result

```
3
4
```

Answer (score 1):

In performance perspective, always try to avoid using inverse keywords like NOT IN, NOT EXISTS. Because to check the inverse items DBMS need to runs through all the available records and drop the inverse selection.

LEFT JOIN / IS NULL and NOT EXISTS are semantically equivalent, while NOT IN is not. These method differ in how they handle NULL values in table_right.

Therefore, You should go for LEFT JOIN to improve your sql performance.

```
select A.id from A LEFT JOIN B 
on A.id = B.id
where B.id is null
order by A.id;
```

Comment: No, this query will return those rows from A table which foreign key column rows on table B is null. So from your question instances, result will be only 3 and 4 from Table A.

Comment: If it return zero rows then this may happen only because there is no null value on table B. This query is fairly correct.